# C# WPF - Automatically put Images in rows

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

Let's say I've a grid and some images which I want to show. What I want to do now is putting the images in a straight row. If they don't fit inside the grids width anymore, they shall be put in the next row. I feel like there has to be a way to do that automatically, like the LayoutManager in Java for example. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us your existing XAML.

Comment: Well the point is that I've just a grid and nothing else. The images shall get added by code, which I've already done, but my question is how I can fit them in rows, so THIS code isn't rly necessary to the question

Comment: Ok thanks for the hints ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use wrap- or a stackpanel inside your cell and set some alignments (for example set verticalAlignment to "strech").

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

Comment: WrapPanel seems to be exactly what I was searching for! thanks!
But is there also a way to define the space between the components in it. I don't need multiple different ones, I just want a space in general between them.

Comment: Add margin on images